# Sorting SUM of Calculated Field by other value in Table with SQL

Tags: sql, calculated-field

I am calculating the "onhand value" of products, multiplying from two fields (Onhand * Price).

Each product belongs to a class, and I want to know the total onhand value of all products within each product class.

Not sure how to do this? Here's my code:

```
SELECT Class, (OnHand * PtPrice)
FROM PART
GROUP BY Class, (OnHand*PtPrice);
```

This lists the the class for each item, and that item's value. But I want the class to be a single column and the total of all calculated onhand values for that class to be shown. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I'm working in Access 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `SUM` aggregate to the calculation part and remove the calculation part from `group by`

```
SELECT Class, SUM(OnHand * PtPrice)
FROM PART
GROUP BY Class;
```

Comment: Thank you! As someone new to coding and attempting to self-learn, I really do appreciate your consideration of my question.